# How to load file in file chooser in website from java application

Tags: java, dictionary, awt

I have a java application on which button click I need to load a file from the system in the file chooser of the website.

The website can be any website not created by me.

```
private void submitButton(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        Desktop d=Desktop.getDesktop();
        d.browse(new URI("http://example.com"));
    }
```

now say on this URI there is one File Chooser which i want to be load with some file from my local system.

Comment: Do you have any code people can look at.

Comment: private void submitButton(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        Desktop d=Desktop.getDesktop();
        d.browse(new URI("http://example.com"));
    }

   


now say on this URI there is one File Chooser which i want to be load with some file from my local system.

Comment: Put the code under your question, by editing your question my friend.

Comment: What do you mean, a "file from your website"?

Comment: No @DaveNewton , i mean to automate the process of choosing the file on website from java application . like we have file chooser on various website on which we upload files .

Comment: I see. Then you'll need to drive a browser through something like Selenium.